# Receiving a data array via JSR223 PreProcessor jmeter

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

Task:

- there are 2 requests
- the first request contains data. their number can be from 0 to 20
  — in the second request you need to send a real list of this data in the parameters of the second request. There may be 20 lines, or there may be 0
- in the first query using **Regular Expression Extractor** I extract all the data into a variable VAR.
- then in the second request I added **JSR223 PreProcessor**

And here’s the question: what code should I add to it to solve my problem and pass the values I receive to the body of this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot tell you "what code should you add to it to solve your problem" because we don't know how JMeter Variables originating from the Regular Expression Extractor look like and how do you need to transform them for the next request. In other words in order to get a comprehensive answer you need to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

---

To give you an overall idea regarding what steps you need to take:

If [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) returns multiple matches like:

```
VAR_1=foo
VAR_2=bar
VAR_3=baz
VAR_matchNr=3
```

you can create an "array" from them in the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like:

```
def array = []

1.upto(vars.get('VAR_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    array.add(vars.get('VAR_' + index))
})

vars.put('array', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(array).toPrettyString())
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: you were right, RegEx does return several matches that look like
VAR_1=foo
VAR_2=bar
VAR_3=baz
VAR_matchNr=3
The example you provided works, I get the values.
But now another problem has arisen. In the body of the request I pass the variable ${array} I pass it as 1 parameter.
In this case, the entire array of data is transmitted at once in the request headers in 1 parameter
[
     "373",
     "372",
     "371",
     "370"
]
How can I make sure that the request header contains as many parameters as there are values in the data array?

Comment: Your answer helped, thanks! I will formalize the next question separately as it should be according to the rules of the resource